# Unable to load textured Collada exported from blender using Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, blender, collada

I am using Three.js, **version 71**. I'm using Blender, **version 2.73**.

I created a textured collada object (.dae file) using Blender, and now I want to load it into my three.js scene. So far, I can only load models that get exported from blender that have no textures on them.

**Here is how I create the textured collada object:**
In blender, I simply use the default cube. Using the settings on the right, I add a texture to the cube. Here is the texture I am putting onto the cube (NOTE: it is 2048 X 2048, so it's a power of 2):
[image: Texture for Collada (2048 X 2048)]

Here is an image of the cube in render mode to prove that the texture is on it:
[image: Textured Collada]

Here are the export settings I used when I exported the cube as a collada from Blender:
[image: Collada Export Settings]

**Here is some code I used to try to load the textured collada:**

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var localObject;
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( './models/test_texture.dae', function ( collada ) {
  localObject = collada.scene;
  localObject.scale.x = localObject.scale.y = localObject.scale.z = 32;
  localObject.updateMatrix();
  game.scene.add(localObject);
} );
```

Here is the error I got:

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2
```

I then googled that error message and someone said the I need to compute tangents. Here are my attempts at that and the errors I got:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var localObject;
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( './models/test_texture.dae', function ( collada ) {
  localObject = collada.scene;
  localObject.scale.x = localObject.scale.y = localObject.scale.z = 32;
  localObject.updateMatrix();

  for (var i = collada.scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var child = collada.scene.children[i];

    // child.children[0] will give us the THREE.Mesh of the collada
    if ( child.colladaId == "Cube" ) {

      // ATTEMPT 1: Just tried computing tangets based on answer from neoRiley here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200386/webgl-gl-error-gl-invalid-operation-gldrawelements-attempt-to-access-out-of
      // child.children[0].geometry.computeTangents();

      // ATTEMPT 2: Got this suggestion from Popov here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717468/three-lod-and-normalmap-shader-fail
      // child.children[0].geometry[ 0 ][ 0 ].computeTangents();
      // child.children[0].geometry[ 1 ][ 0 ].computeTangents();

      // ATTEMPT 3: Tried setting some update flags based on answer from Sayris here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988615/webglrenderingcontext-error-loading-texture-maps
      // child.children[0].geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
      // child.children[0].geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
      // child.children[0].material.needsUpdate = true;
      // child.children[0].geometry.computeTangents();
    }
  };
  game.scene.add(localObject);
} );
```

**ATTEMPT 1 ERROR:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
// Stack trace
three.js:9935 handleTriangle
three.js:9974 THREE.Geometry.computeTangents
myCode.js:116 (anonymous function)
ColladaLoader.js:204 parse
ColladaLoader.js:84 request.onreadystatechange
```

**ATTEMPT 2 ERROR:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This came from own code. I didn't think geometry of THREE.Mesh is two dimensional, but I tried it anyway.

**ATTEMPT 3 ERROR: (same as ATTEMPT 1 ERROR)**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
// Stack trace
three.js:9935 handleTriangle
three.js:9974 THREE.Geometry.computeTangents
myCode.js:116 (anonymous function)
ColladaLoader.js:204 parse
ColladaLoader.js:84 request.onreadystatechange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the **JSON** loader instead because I couldn't get the collada one to work. The first thing I did was install the JSON exporter addon into Blender. I got the addon from the .zip file from my three.js download. It's in 
**three.js-r71/utils/exporters/blender/addons** and it's called **io_three**. You just need to copy that folder and paste it in your Blender installation directory in **Blender Foundation/Blender/2.73/scripts/addons**.

You then have to enable it in Blender. To do that:

1. Click to **File->User Preferences...**
2. Click **Add-ons**
3. Type **three** in the search field
4. All the way to the right, click the check box to enable it
5. At the bottom left, click **Save User Settings** so you don't need to do this again. You'll know it's working if you see **Three.js (.json)** when you click **File->Export**.

I followed most of the instructions from this site to help me create and export a model: http://graphic-sim.com/B_basic_export.html

Here are the steps I used to create and export the model (I tweaked them a little bit from the site)

1. Start up Blender.
2. Look at the Properties editor (on the right).
3. Press the **World** context button. In the **World** panel click **Ambient Color** and change it from black to middle gray.
4. Press the **Material** context button. On the **Diffuse** panel change **Intensity** to 1.0. Do the same on the **Specular** panel. In the **Shading** panel put a check in the **Shadeless** box.
5. Press the **Textures** context button. Near the top in the **Type** drop down box, select **Image or Movie**. In the **Image** panel, browse to your image (make sure the image's dimensions are in a power of 2).
6. Choose the **UV Editing** screen layout (drop-down box to right of help menu at top).
   [image: UV Editing menu]
7. With mouse cursor in 3D editor, go into edit mode (Tab key).
8. Unwrap (Press the **U** key). Choose **Smart UV Project**. Click **Ok** to accept defaults.
9. In the UV Editing screen, select your image using the menu at the bottom left (see screenshot)
   [image: Selecting Image in UV layout]
10. Select **Image->Save As Image**. This image will need to be next to your JSON file that you will export.
11. Click **File->Export->Three.js (.json)**.
12. To the left, select a few more export options (see screenshot for the ones i used, which I found by trial and error). I think I only added **Face Materials**, **Materials**, and **Textures**. You can then also click **Save Settings** to save these settings.
    [image: JSON Export Settings]
13. Put your JSON file and your image file that you saved earlier in your project folder.
14. Use the following code to load it:

    ```
    var object;
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();          
    loader.load( "./models/test_texture.json", function(geometry, materials) {
      object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials[0]);
      object.scale.set(32, 32, 32);
      game.scene.add(object);
    });
    ```